# What is a good tutorial for Django other than the Django documentation?

Tags: django

What is a good tutorial for Django other than the Django documentation? I need a tutorial to get some expertise with Django.

Comment: Use the search in the upper right hand corner. There are a ton of posts about this. This might give you some links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145414/what-are-the-best-books-and-resources-for-learning-to-develop-deploy-and-or-host/1145440#1145440

Comment: +1. I'm suddenly interested in this topic so I can point others to a 2011 list of resources. Perhaps it's time to start one? Following and going to sleep.

Comment: ya that will help many noob users like me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know your background, but I would have liked someone to have told me when I started with Django to go over the basics of programming for the web. It's quite different to programming normal desktop applications. I learned a lot of things the hard way. (Even simple things like HTTP/POST/GET, the difference between desktop patterns and web application patterns, etc.).

It's important to understand what Django is, and what it isn't. It might be a nice idea to try a very stripped down framework (like [Flask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28programming%29) for example) in tandem, as it will highlight the 'heavy lifting' Django takes care of. Django abstracts a lot of things meaning you don't have to worry about them. While this is great to start with (you don't have to worry about sessions, authentication, etc.) you will eventually find yourself having to come to terms with them.

Furthermore, I probably should have sat down and learned Python before diving in.

Once you have the basics, Django is quite straightforward; the easiest way is to attempt a simple starter project, that is, a blog, CMS or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check out [The Django book (2.0)](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/). This is the perfect second tutorial as it covers much much more in the same fantastic documentation style. It's also green.

There's [also this list of tutorials on the djangoproject.com wiki](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Tutorials) but it's kind of outdated.

Beyond the Django book, I just started building stuff and googled the problems I ran into.

Comment: The Django book is just over 2 years old now...

Comment: @Mark, yeah, but still relevant. I'm not having an easy time finding another definitive django tutorial #2. I wish this wasn't closed, since the latest answers in that thread are 2 years old as well.